# Can't control audio volume on device using AudioToolbox code in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I created an app and used the following code to produce sound.

```
func playPianoButtonSound(button: UIButton) {
var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(
    CFBundleGetMainBundle(), pianoButtonsSoundNames[button], "wav", nil)
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
}
```

Sometimes it works and responds to the external volume control and sometimes it does not. Has anyone encountered this problem, if so I'd like to hear their experience and how they solved the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: System sounds, to the best of my knowledge, don't allow you to control the volume at which they are played--they're controlled by the system volume. Try using AVAudioPlayer (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/)

Comment: I just found that out myself thank you. I am using system sounds because I need a fast response and low latency since I am using this to play piano sounds. AVAudioPlayer wouldn't do the job. I am just wondering if there is something wrong in the code I currently have that makes that volume glitch happen when I start the app right away..